# Joomla : Breezing form's shortcode is not working on 2.5.6

Tags: joomla2.5, shortcode, breezingforms

I have upgraded Joomla site from Version 1.5.23 to Version 2.5.6. In older version, the Breezing form shortcode is working fine but not one newer version.

In newer version site, I am using Breezing Forms (Lite) extension.

For example :

Link of older version site where breezing form is working :

http://www.vut-research.ac.za/index.php/component/content/article/44-research/242-invitations

Link of new version site where breezing form is not working :
http://testvut.viewmysitenow.com/index.php/46-home/articles/44-research/242-invitations

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you have installed and enabled Breezingforms plugin under `Extensions -> Plugin Manager`.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!